# Where are the harpies in the Sackful of Fluff Quest?

Tags: the-witcher-2

So I'm attempting to gather 60 harpy feathers for this Sackful of Fluff quest - I know that harpies generally spawn right outside the house where you initiate the quest (that's where I went to get the first 12 feathers for the first part of the quest anyway) - but now that I'm trying to get the rest, none of the harpies are respawning?

As an aside, I was doing this quest in tandem with the Harpy Contract also in Chapter 2 - I planted those traps here and they carried them back to their nests (and presumably died/destroyed the nest).  Would that have anything to do with why the harpies aren't spawning again?

Comment: have you tried meditating to pass time to see if they respawn?

Comment: Yep! I meditated in Vergen for an entire day, went back around midnight, still no spawns.  I then meditated again in the questgiver's house, another 24 hours, still nothing.

It's not that NO monsters are spawning, as there are Nekkers and junk around the area, but no harpies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a final note - I managed to complete the quest, though I had to kill a bunch of the harpies in the Quarry instead to do so.  I think the fact that I tried to complete two quests at once (the harpy contract) made things difficult - using the traps on them will essentially stop them from respawning (as you're killing the harpy along with its nest).

Funnily enough, after completing sackful of fluff, harpies began to respawn outside Elthon's house, though in a much smaller number than before.

Answer (score 0):

Placing Harpy Traps (Harpy Contract) greatly affects the spawn rate of harpies near their nests, so you should do that only after killing as many harpies as you need.

Also, I heard that killing the Harpy Queen also reduces the spawn rate, but haven't noticed any changes myself.